# Usage of participles

Tags: past-participles, participle-clauses, participle-phrases, participial-adjectives

> she went out dissapointed

Vs

> She went out dissapointedly.

What is the difference in meaning of these two sentences

Comment: You misspelled *disappointed*.

Comment: Perhaps the second sentence describes her *manner* of leaving, and others can see her disappointment. The first sentence might just describe her inner state.

Answer (score 1):

*-ly* turns an adjective (or a participle being used like an adjective) into an adverb.

Adjectives modify nouns, adverbs modify verbs (or adjectives or other adverbs).

The effect is that this turns a word that says "what kind of X is X" into a word that says "how is X done".

> she went out disappointed

This means she was disappointed (*disappointed* complements *she* - "went out" is being used copularly like *be*, *seem*, *become*, etc.).

> she went out disappointedly

This means she went out in a disappointed way (*disappointedly* complements the verb phrase "went out" - explaining *how* she went out).

Now, you probably won't go out in a disappointed manner if you aren't disappointed, so both these expressions do lead to the same conclusion, but in a different way.